Is there code or a function in Python to apply LWR to an NDVI time series?
I want to apply a LWR to a NDVI time series which is a union between estimates for Sentinel and Landsat, to smooth the values ​​and then make a daily interpolation.
The scripts that exist on the web and I've seen are not time series oriented. I would like to know if the same ones can be applied, what the modifications would be or if the approach is completely different.
Thanks,

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
